# Redirect from Safari App Extension Content Blocker

Tags: redirect, safari-app-extension, safari-content-blocker

In a Safari App Extension Content Blocker, am I able to assign an `action` to a `trigger` that allows me to redirect to another page instead of blocking it outright?

Answer (score 0):

Safari Content blocker only supports the following actions

**block**

Stops loading of the resource. If the resource was cached, the cache is ignored.

**block-cookies**

Strips cookies from the header before sending to the server. Only cookies otherwise acceptable to Safari's privacy policy can be blocked. Combining with ignore-previous-rules doesn't override the browser’s privacy settings.

**css-display-none**

Hides elements of the page based on a CSS selector. A selector field contains the selector list. Any matching element has its display property set to none, which hides it.

**ignore-previous-rules**

Ignores previously triggered actions.

**make-https**

Changes a URL from http to https. URLs with a specified (nondefault) port and links using other protocols are unaffected.